# How to print only time in java?

Tags: java

```
DateFormat dateFormatOne = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatOne.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date dateOne = dateFormatOne.parse("10:00:00");
```

Comment: For java 8 `System.out.print(LocalTime.of(10, 0, 0));`

Comment: @ButiriDan: i can only use Data class

Comment: @ilovejava What Dat**a** class? Or dud you mean Dat**e** class?

Answer (score 2):

- **format** convert date to string
- **parse** convert string to date

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormatOne = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatOne.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date dateOne = dateFormatOne.parse("10:00:00");

    System.out.println(dateFormatOne.format(dateOne));
    System.out.println(dateFormatOne.format(new Date()));
}
```

**Output**

```
10:00:00
20:20:55
```

But I recommend Java 8

```
System.out.print(LocalTime.of(10, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the current local time on the machine running the program you can use LocalTime.

```
import java.time.LocalTime; // import the LocalTime class

public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    LocalTime myTime = LocalTime.now();
    System.out.println(myTime);
  } 
}
```

Comment: my requirement is to use Date class.

Comment: Date class has been depreciated. You can do it with the Calendar, LocalTime or LocalDateTime classes though. Before it was depreciated you would just do Date nowTime = new Date(); int hours = nowTime.getHours(); int minutes = nowTime.getMinutes(); int seconds = nowTime.getSeconds();